# Is it possible to do REGEX in build.gradle for a string?

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, version

I have the following line of code in my build.gradle at the app level

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.resValue "string", "versionName", "Version " + variant.versionName
}
```

Is there a way to perform a regex and only grab a specific portion of the

```
variant.versionName
```

It returns me something like 2.56.2-alpharc and i want to remove everything except the numbers at the beginning to get 2.56.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. You can use a regular java code with regular expressions or some groovy specific code:

For java approach, something along:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+).*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(variant.versionName);
    matcher.find()
    def strippedVersion = matcher.group(1)
```

For groovy approach:

```
    def matcher = variant.versionName =~ /^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*/
    matcher.find()
    def strippedVersion = matcher.group(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If i understand correctly it is saying that it must find a pattern that starts with \\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+ , but why is there a period after the entire pattern? When I search up it means matchs any cahracter?

Comment: I think I'm confused about what .* means

Comment: The `.*` matches any character zero or more times. I added it to match the remainder of the string, but it might not be necessary.